Closed form for $\Gamma(a-x)$ where $a \in (0,1]$.
Now asked on MO here.

I wonder if there is a closed form for $ \Gamma(a-x)$.
And by closed form here I mean a finite combinations of elementary functions, powers of $\Gamma(a)$ and powers of $\Gamma(kx)$ where $k$ is real, any other representation involving any other  special functions like beta are not what I am looking for.
The closed form is known when $a=1$ being the famous formula $\frac{\pi}{\Gamma(x)\sin(\pi x)}$  (and automatically the closed form exist for all integer  $a$). Since $\Gamma\left( x+\frac{1}{2}\right)\Gamma\left( x\right)= \frac{\sqrt{\pi} \  \Gamma(2x)}{{2^{2x-1}}}$ one can find the formula when $a=\frac{1}{2}$ being $$\frac{\sqrt{\pi}  \  \Gamma(x) 2^{2x-1} }{\sin\left(\pi x +\frac{\pi}{2}\right)\Gamma(2x)}$$
(also the closed form exist for all $n+ \frac{1}{2}$ where $n \in \mathbb{N}$ in general we need to find a closed form for $a\in(0,1]$)
I don't think a  closed form exist for all $a$ but at least they exist for some values. Is there is any other closed form for other values than $1, \frac 1 2 $? I couldn't find closed form for any other values.

Similar question, but removed.

Do you know about the relationship to ${}_2F_1$?

@Jakob No, I have never heard of it.

@ТymaGaidash Wait, how did you find a deleted question?

I would consider $\Gamma(a-z)$ to already be "closed form".

@K.defaoite I know that but could it be represented via powers of $\gamma(kz)$ and powers of $\gamma(a)$ only ?

@pie I can't imagine why an incomplete Gamma funcion would be a better "closed form" for any practical purpose than $\Gamma(a-z)$.

@pie ${}_2F_1$ is a hypergeometric function and there are also formula's related to the $\Gamma$ function. I believe my answer is more appropriate to your question.

@K.defaoite I didn't say it was useful, it seemed to be an interesting thing to do for me.

I think the following identity is different from the reflection formula and is valid except for arguments for which the $\Gamma$ function is undefined namely the negative integers:
$$ \Gamma(a-x) =\frac{\sqrt{\pi}\; \Gamma(2a-2x-1)}{4^{a-x-1}\;\Gamma(a-x-\frac{1}{2})} $$
